# Reloading Servlet?

Tags: java, servlets

I'm new to servlets so bear with me.

I want to make a servlet that writes a standard table with default values (e.g. 2 rows, 2 columns) with underneath two text values.

In these textboxes I want to fill in the wanted rows and columns.  After these text values are filled in the table must change to the requested form.

At this moment I get a 404 error

```
/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
 *      response)
 */
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    doPost(request, response);
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
 *      response)
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("Text/html");
    PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
    pw.println("<html><body>");
    pw.println("<h1>Table generator</h1><table border=1>");

    Integer row = (Integer) request.getAttribute("rows");
    Integer col = (Integer) request.getAttribute("cols");

    if (row != null && col != null) {

        for (int i = 1; i < col; i++) {
            pw.print(HtmlUtils.getTH("center", "COL" + i));
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        Vector av = new Vector();

        for (int i = 1; i < row; i++) {

            for (int y = 1; i < col; y++) {

                av.addElement("index" + col + "." + y);

            }
        }

    } else {

        pw.print(HtmlUtils.getTableHead("center", 1));

        pw.print(HtmlUtils.getTH("center", "COL1"));
        pw.print(HtmlUtils.getTH("center", "COL2"));

        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        Vector av = new Vector();

        for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {

            av.addElement("index1." + i);
            av.addElement("index2." + i);

        }

        pw.print(HtmlUtils.getTableContents("center", av, 2));

    }

    pw.println("</table>");

    pw.println("<form action='input' method='post'>");
    pw.println("Rows : <input type='text' name='rows'><br>");
    pw.println("Cols : <input type='text' name='cols'><br>");
    pw.println("<input type='submit'>");
    pw.println("</form></body></html>");
}
```

Any suggestions

Comment: A 404 just means that the URL as you see in browser's address bar is wrong. This has not much to do with servlets. You should make sure that the URL is correct or that you have something listening on that URL. Although I'd like to warn that this is not the right way to use servlets. It should only contain Java code, not HTML code. HTML belongs in JSP. See also our servlets wiki page for some Hello World examples. You can get there by hovering your mouse on `[servlets]` tag which you put on the question until a black box shows up and then click therein the *info* link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your code it looks like you might be confused between request attributes and parameters.

After filling in the values, the user should click the submit button for the form. You'll need to configure the form to submit to the same servlet. This servlet can then do whatever processing is required (e.g. store the values a database) and redisplay the web page, but it should check and see what values (if any) the user has put in the form. If they have filled in either of the two text values, the servlet can put these values into the table.

Suppose your form looks like this:

```
<form name="input" action="your-servlet-name.action" method="get">
  Text1: <input type="text" name="text1">
  Text2: <input type="text" name="text2">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

The action attribute of the form must be set to the URL where your servlet is.
In your Java code you can call request.getParameter("text1") etc to get the values that the user has typed in.

In the code as written, you are trying to access request attributes, which aren't the same as parameters. Parameters are values sent from the browser. Attributes are values inserted into the request by Java code on the server.